# texbox con limite

Tags: c#

Como hago para que mi textbox permita numero de hasta 5 dígitos

mi textbox ya diferencia entre letras y números que quedo así

```
int TheCode = 0;
            if(int.TryParse(txtCodigo.Text, out TheCode) == false)
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(txtCodigo, "Ingrese solo Números");
                txtCodigo.Focus();
                return;
            }
```

digamos que ingreso 12345, mi código si verifica si es numero o no pero después de eso no se como ponerle un limite de 5 digitos y si pasa ese limite que haga aparecer el ErrorProvider

Comment: Y si escribes, menos de 5 dígitos ej, 1234, que pasa, esta bien o obligatoriamente tienes que llenar el text box con 5 digitos

Answer (score 0):

Podría servirte algo como esto, de modo que si pasa la verificación de si es o no un nro., la siguiente condición evalúa si el cuadro de texto tiene mas de 5 dígitos en este caso (quitándole los espacios en blanco con .Trim()).

Particularmente te sugeriría guardar como un parámetro el valor limite(en este caso 5) ya que es probable que pueda cambiar, para no tener que modificar tu programa por eso

```
        int TheCode = 0;
        int limite = 5; //limite de 5 digitos
        if(int.TryParse(txtCodigo.Text, out TheCode) == false)
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtCodigo, "Ingrese solo Números");
            txtCodigo.Focus();
            return;
        }
        if(txtCodigo.Text.Trim().Lenght > limite)
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtCodigo, $"No puede superar el maximo de {limite} 
                                    digitos");
            txtCodigo.Focus();
            return;
        }
```

También podrías evaluar las dos condiciones en un solo If, pero de este modo solo tendrías un mensaje que englobe las dos validaciones

```
            int TheCode = 0;
            int limite = 5; //limite de 5 digitos
            if(int.TryParse(txtCodigo.Text, out TheCode) == false || txtCodigo.Text.Trim().Lenght > limite)
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(txtCodigo, $"Debe ingresar un Nro de {limite} digitos");
                txtCodigo.Focus();
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si la cantidad de dígitos es conocida en tiempo de compilación puedes simplificar la función de chequeo de la siguiente manera:

```
if (int.TryParse(txtCodigo.Text, out int val) && (Math.Abs(val) <= 99999)) {
    ...el número es correcto y dentro de los límites...
} else {
    errorProvider1.SetError(txtCodigo, "Ingrese solo Números con hasta cinco dígitos");
}
```

Si quieres diferenciar entre los dos posibles errores entonces lo puedes hacer así también:

```
    if (!int.TryParse(txtCodigo.Text, out int val)) {
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtCodigo, "Ingrese solo Números");
    } else if (Math.Abs(val) <= 99999) {
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtCodigo, "Ingrese solo Números con hasta cinco dígitos");
    } else {
        ...el número es correcto y dentro de los límites...
    }
```

En ambos casos admite números negativos, pero eso lo puedes limitar más si quieres.